# How can you get a dynamically named variable in handlebars?

Tags: handlebars.js, mustache

I am trying to output a table using handlebars.

Right now it loops through the each row, and then through each column, but how can I grab the data from the row based on {{col.name}}?

See here, I need to get COLUMNNAME from {{col.name}}

```
{{#rows as |row|}}
  <tr>
    {{#../cols as |col|}}
      <td>{{row.COLUMNNAME}}</td>
    {{/../cols}}
  </tr>
{{/rows}}
```

In js this would be like row[index][col.name];

Any idea for solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer, it's the lookup tag.

```
{{lookup row col.name}}
```

is equal to

```
row[col.name]
```